pyparsing - back to basics
In attempting to put together a very simple example to illustrate an issue I'm having with pyparsing, I have found that I can't get my simple example to work - this example is barely more complex than Hello, World!
Here is my example code:
import pyparsing as pp
import textwrap as tw

text = (
    """
    A) Red
    B) Green
    C) Blue
    """
)

a = pp.AtLineStart("A)") + pp.Word(pp.alphas)
b = pp.AtLineStart("B)") + pp.Word(pp.alphas)
c = pp.AtLineStart("C)") + pp.Word(pp.alphas)

grammar = a + b + c

grammar.run_tests(tw.dedent(text).strip())

I would expect it to return ["A)", "Red", "B)", "Green", "C)", "Blue"] but instead I get:
A) Red
A) Red
      ^
ParseException: not found at line start, found end of text  (at char 6), (line:1, col:7)
FAIL: not found at line start, found end of text  (at char 6), (line:1, col:7)

B) Green
B) Green
^
ParseException: Expected 'A)', found 'B'  (at char 0), (line:1, col:1) 
FAIL: Expected 'A)', found 'B'  (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)

C) Blue
C) Blue
^
ParseException: Expected 'A)', found 'C'  (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)
FAIL: Expected 'A)', found 'C'  (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)

Why would it say it's found end of text after the first line??? Why is it expecting A) after the first line???
(Note: textwrap.dedent() and strip() have no impact on the results of this script.)

My dude! You forgot to wrap raw string into a list!
I tested for 30 mins and felt something was odd, then found this in document:

run_tests(tests: Union[str, List[str]], ...) -> ...
Execute the parse expression on a series of test strings, showing each test, the parsed results or where the parse failed. Quick and easy way to run a parse expression against a list of sample strings.
Parameters:
tests - a list of separate test strings, or a multiline string of test strings

Basically you (and me for last half hour) by doing this:
grammar.run_tests(tw.dedent(text).strip())

...Was telling it to treat each line as individual tests!
"""  # You are a test 0 now!
    A) Red  # You are a test 1
    B) Green  # test 2 for you,
    C) Blue  # test 3 for ya,
""" # finally you're test 4! Mhahahah!

(And of course the use of pp.line_end so line actually consume end of line)
>>> import pyparsing as pp
... import textwrap as tw
...
... text = (
...     """
...     A) Red
...     B) Green
...     C) Blue
...     """
... )
...
... a = pp.AtLineStart("A)") + pp.Word(pp.alphas) + pp.line_end.suppress()
... b = pp.AtLineStart("B)") + pp.Word(pp.alphas) + pp.line_end.suppress()
... c = pp.AtLineStart("C)") + pp.Word(pp.alphas)
...
... grammar = a + b + c
... grammar.run_tests([tw.dedent(text).strip()])


A) Red
B) Green
C) Blue
['A)', 'Red', 'B)', 'Green', 'C)', 'Blue']
>>>


Thanks for your response @jupiterbjy! I actually do want + as the text I'm parsing has six tokens and my grammar has six elements that should each match one token. Using |, as you have done, would match A) Red\nA) Green\nA) Blue but that is not a valid input to my parser - the keywords A), B), and C) are significant, and must appear in order.

I forgot to say: the functions textwrap.dedent() and strip() are there to mirror the script I'm trying to debug; I feel like pyparsing isn't handling whitespace properly (despite the documentation saying that it ignores whitespace!). textwrap.dedent() is necessary in this case because AtLineStart() won't match my keywords if they're indented - I have confirmed that the input I am attempting to parse does, in fact have the keywords immediately after the newline character.

@MichaelHenry I wonder if there's some hidden carriage return or some tabs in that source.. interesting. Can you update the answer to include those details too?

Thank you so much @jupiterbjy! Exceptional work! I knew, when I posted this, that I would be embarrassed. It all comes down to my lack of Python skillz ;) I wrapped my test text in parentheses because, in my mind, that's how you create a list (thank you lisp!). To me, square brackets are for arrays (I still love you, C), which was the primary cause of my problem.

@MichaelHenry oh you can do same in tuple! But since in python (and some other languages) one uses () to allow moving the R-Value off the L-Value in case L-Value become way too long or etc - it's not distinguishable from single-value tuple definition so we use (val,)  to indicate that this indeed is single value tuple (that trailing comma). Btw I still remember professor giving me Lisp and Prolog HW to implement bubble sort and n-queen, amazing people can be smart enough to use that in my perspective!

Oh and since in python list are like std::vector<std::variant> not linked list so... in some way it can be an array at least internally? Altho the "real arrays" in python looks kinda different tho, like import array \ array.array("typecode", Iterable) but mostly initialized with lists like array.array("i", [1, 2, 3]) - this might be helpful for remembering!

Thanks for your persistence in learning your way around in pyparsing! There is definitely a flaw in the AtLineStart docs that is getting in your way, which I'll fix this afternoon or this evening.
First off, here is the code from the AtLineStart docstring:
import pyparsing as pp

# from the docstring for AtLineStart
test = '''\
AAA this line
AAA and this line
  AAA but not this one
B AAA and definitely not this one
'''

for t in (pp.AtLineStart('AAA') + pp.rest_of_line).search_string(test):
    print(t)

Almost like your example, but with some important differences. This code works because it uses search_string. AtLineStart does not skip whitespace - it will ONLY match at the start of the line. In retrospect, the use of search_string was a poor one, since it masks the strict line-start matching that AtLineStart does.
The problem in your example is that after parsing the Word(pp.alphas) after "A)", the parser is positioned at the \n at the end of the line - AtLineStart ONLY matches if it is positioned at the character that is the first character in the entire input string, or the first character after a newline.
We fix this by explicitly parsing the newline:
# You'll see the \n's in the output - suppress this if you don't like them
NL = pp.LineEnd()
a = pp.AtLineStart("A)") + pp.Word(pp.alphas) + NL
b = pp.AtLineStart("B)") + pp.Word(pp.alphas) + NL
c = pp.AtLineStart("C)") + pp.Word(pp.alphas) + NL

grammar = a + b + c

As @jupiterbjy helpfully pointed out, when run_tests is given a single string, it treats it kind of like doctest, with each line being its own separate test (you can actually intersperse blank lines and '#' comments to annotate the test output too). To force run_tests to work with a multiline test, make it a single line with \n's, or wrap the triple-quoted string in []'s, to explicitly create your own list of tests - this list can then contain multiple multiline test strings.
Here is the code I used to try to parse your input and to show the exception:
try:
    result = grammar.parse_string(textwrap.dedent(text).strip())
except ParseException as pe:
    print(pp.testing.with_line_numbers(textwrap.dedent(text).strip(), eol_mark="<"))
    print(pe.explain())
else:
    print(result.dump())

With your original grammar, this prints:
            1
   1234567890
 1:A) Red<
 2:B) Green<
 3:C) Blue<

A) Red
      ^
ParseException: not found at line start, found '\n'  (at char 6), (line:1, col:7)

With the added NL terms, you'll see:
['A)', 'Red', '\n', 'B)', 'Green', '\n', 'C)', 'Blue']

(Rereading @jupiterbjy's answer, it looks like they included the "parse the line ends" suggestion also, so theirs would be the good answer to accept, and mine can just be "yeah, what they said" independent confirmation.)

Thank you @PaulMcG! I'm still processing... but I think what you're saying is that pyparsing will ignore whitespace unless you use AtLineStart(), in which case newlines have to be handled explicitly. Are there any other functions which trigger this requirement?

I'm not gonna sugarcoat that pyparsing might need more examples on documents for dummies like me who had to search hours how to use line_end/LineEnd() from zero base - But darn, this is one very interactive and fun way to create parser! Begone, the pain of YACC and Lexer! I now will die using this for all the parser need I'll ever have in lifetime!

Yes, I am finding it an intuitive way to write a parser.
